# Facebook caches the open graph tags of pages before they are publicly available which results in the wrong data being shared

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We use Drupal 5 as CMS and whenever publish an article and share it to Facebook it displays the wrong preview data. For example, the description becomes "No access". We have open graph meta tags on the page, but it seems like Facebook scrapes our page on a moment when our article is not published to the public yet.

The solution is to debug every url with the facebook linter/debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). We could use curl to do that. However, recently you have to log on to use the debugger. And more recently you have to push the button "Debug" too.

Who recognizes this problem and can you share your solution?

Comment: Could you conditionally expose those tags based on if the article is published?

Comment: Do you mean we should expose the tags even when the article is not published?

Comment: I mean do not expose the tags when the article is not published.  Only expose them when there is valid content on the article.

Comment: That's a great suggestion! We will try this and I'll report back.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it. Facebook still caches the "no access" description of the page when the page is still drafted (and not visible to the public). When does Facebook first cache the tags of the page? Why doesn't it honor the 403-error?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this. Apparently we had a script that was polling facebook for the number of shares of an article. This script was being called even when the article wasn't live to the public. That's why and when Facebook cached the "no access" page. We removed the script on unpublished articles and the issue was gone.

Thanks!